# jQuery and ASP.NET advantages

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am so confused that I thought to ask you for your opinion.

I have written few jquery code with asp.net. But there is group of developer in my company who think that javascript/jquery can be turned off and is insecure

- if javascript is insecure, why to use it at the first place
- what are the advantages of using jquery with asp.net apart from cross-browser. why not use javascript?
- should i use jquery in my asp.net applications?

There were a few posts over here that contained similar question, but not even one that contained good explanation. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Not a full answer, just a partial...  As to whether you should use it, I think the important thing is the *if* you use a library of any type, try to make sure that your site works with JavaScript turned off.  JavaScript form submits, links, etc. are an SEO killer and also are frustrating to users who have JS disabled, either by choice or by circumstance.

Answer (score 4):

> if javascript is insecure, why to use it at the first place

To provide advanced browsing experience to those who have it on.

> what are the advantages of using jquery with asp.net apart from cross-browser. why not use javascript?

Rapid development. If you're not comfortable with jQuery, code in JavaScript directly, see no problem here.

> should i use jquery in my asp.net applications?

That's up to you to decide. Give it a try and see if you'll like it.

Answer (score 3):

```
• what are the advantages of using jquery with asp.net apart from cross-browser. 
  why not use javascript?
```

jQuery *is* javascript. The purpose of javascript is to enhance the user's browser experience. If this is something you want to include in your website then I would advise you use it. If you do opt to use it, depending on what your requirements are, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is no less secure than using the Internet.  I would definitely recommend it for the sheer purpose of enhancing the user experience.  However, it is also important to make sure your application functions properly with Javascript disabled.

How you write your Javascript is up to you.  I use jQuery because I am much more productive with it, primarily because I don't waste time dealing with the inherent short-comings of Javascript, as well as the numerous cross-browser oddities.  jQuery is, in fact, Javascript, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

1. To provide a better experience for the users.  People today expect web pages to be interactive.  The idea of having a totally static site died a while ago.  It should also be said, that if someone is really skilled at compromising systems, whether you use JavaScript or not is inconsequential.  With cross site scripting attacks etc. someone can embed JavaScript into your site.  Using JavaScript might make it easier to compromise a page, but not using, doesn't mean that it is fool proof protection against it.
2. JQuery is a JavaScript framework, and it abstracts a lot of the necessities from knowing the ins and outs of JavaScript and cross browser support.  It also abstracts a lot about what you need to know when manipulating the DOM, which can be extremely frustrating at times.  It makes development a lot easier unless you really know what you are doing, and then it still makes development easier in a lot of cases.
3. I would recommend using some sort of a framework unless you are really good with JavaScript.  Jquery may not be the way to go for you, but it is a good one to use.  There are others like Prototype and YUI.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not insecure per se -- but you can certainly create insecure code with it, if you're not careful. All code that is 'critical' security-wise should be run **in the server**, not in the user's browser, because it can be turned off.